# Como acceder al ._id de la base de datos de un objeto recien creado REACT

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, redux

Hola estoy creando una clase de productos en react, y me funciona bien, me crea el objeto pero me gustaria que me trajera el id recien me lo crea, me trae la informacion en redux, pero no se como hacer para acceder a esa informacion. necesito que apenas me cree el objeto me traiga el ._id creado de la base de datos.

este es mi codigo

```
const { loading, error, success } = useSelector(state => state.newService) //este viene del store.js
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (error) {
          alert.error(error)
          dispatch(clearErrors())
        }
        if (success) {
          alert.success('Categorie created successfully');
          dispatch({
            type: CREATE_SERVICE_RESET,
          })
        }
      }, [dispatch, alert, error, success, serviceError, successService])

const GuardarCategoria = () => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.set('nombre', nombre)
    formData.set('descripcion', descripcion)

    alert.success("Se ha creado una nueva categoria")

    dispatch(newService(formData))
    
  }
```

Asi me sale en redux

_id(pin):"63ac8dee407260fdfe5a6250"
nombre(pin):"Michelva"
apellido(pin):"la selva"
email(pin):"m.g@gmail.com"
genero(pin):"Femenino"
role(pin):"admin"
fechaRegistro(pin):"2022-12-28T18:41:50.160Z"
__v(pin):0
resetPasswordExpire(pin):"2023-02-06T00:23:33.802Z"
resetPasswordToken(pin):"f60a200074615f4ec71142eaeb967d2ab9ab99f167d7de397fe0ac2236bdddf3"

y necesito agarrar el _id que se genera automaticamente en mongo

mi codigo en el action y reducer

//crear un servicio ADMIN ACTION

```
export const newService=(serviceData)=>async(dispatch)=>{
    try {
        dispatch({type: CREATE_SERVICE_REQUEST})
        const config={
            header:{'Content-Type':'application/json'}
        }
        const {data}=await axios.post('/api/services/nuevo',serviceData,config)
        
        dispatch({
                type: CREATE_SERVICE_SUCCESS,
                payload:data,
            })
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: CREATE_SERVICE_FAIL,
            payload: error.response.data.message
        })
    }
}
```

REDUCER

```
export const newServiceReducer = (state = { service: {} }, action) =>{
    switch (action.type) {
        case CREATE_SERVICE_REQUEST:
            return{
                ...state,
                loading:true
            }
        case CREATE_SERVICE_SUCCESS:
            return{
                loading: false,
                success:action.payload.success,
                service:action.payload.service
            }
        case CREATE_SERVICE_FAIL:
            return{
                ...state,
                error:action.payload
            }
        case CREATE_SERVICE_RESET:
            return{
                ...state,
                success:false
            }
        case CLEAR_ERRORS:
            return{
                ...state,
                error:null
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Que pongas urgente, no hace que tu pregunta sea mas o menos importante que las otras.. todas son iguales de importantes. El urgente, no agrega nada (y enoja a muchos, lo tuyo no es mas importante que lo del resto ;) )

Comment: Entiendo lo que dices, pero si no sabes del tema mejor no comentas gracias!

Comment: Un moderador electo, esta tratando de ayudarte con tu pregunta, para que no recibas votos negativos, y tambien recibas una respuesta de alguien... uno de mis trabajos es comentar sobre tus preguntas, su forma, sepa o no del tema. ;)...